# Hierarchical page table in OS Memory paging

Tags: operating-system, paging, page-tables

Now I'm studying Memory Management in OS

In Hierarchical page table structure, if there is 32-bit machine, `4KB` of `page-size` and `4B` of `page-entry` size.

why address are the bits divided to `10-10-12`

I know `20 - 12` , `12` bit are `offset` value by 4kbyte -> 2^12

But why 20 bits become 10-10

is it impossible to 11-9 or 12-8?

Answer (score 1):

Because they are using a two level page table. `20-12` would be using only 1 level page table and that consumes memory.

First 10 bits `(0-9)` are the corresponding entry in the `PGDIR`. That entry will point to a page table, in this page table you will access the entry corresponding to second 10 bits. `(10-19)`.

Motivation:

Consider the overhead to store all needed page tables to maintain a single process.
`#pages * size_entry` =  2^20*4 = `4MB`

That is a lot!. 
But what if we used a first level page table which has 1024 entries each pointing to additional 1024 page tables ? that is 1024*1024 = 1M entries just like before.

What is the memory overhead now ?
1K*4 + 1*4 = 4KB + 4B ~= `4KB`